# Xamarin Form Receiving an Arabic DatePicker Binding Error

Tags: xamarin

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between 04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59 (Gregorian date), inclusive.
Parameter name: time

Comment: Check the binding object it has value or not, the error because of null

Comment: does it work now ?

Answer (score 1):

because your `ar-sa` culture's default calender is `UmAlQuraCalendar` calender.Its range is
`1318/01/01` - `1500/12/30` ,
so you should change the date to Gregorian date，

for example ,you get a date `1378/1/1`

```
UmAlQuraCalendar umAlQuraCalendar = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
var datatime = new DateTime(1378,3,1, umAlQuraCalendar);
GregorianCalendar gregorian = new GregorianCalendar();
DateTime gregorianDate  = new DateTime(gregorian.GetYear(datatime), gregorian.GetMonth(datatime), gregorian.GetDayOfMonth(datatime));
Console.WriteLine("ar-sa----" + gregorianDate  .ToString());//the result will be:"ar-sa----9/14/1958 12:00:00 AM"
```